# Pandas, 'nan' fields after changing column datatypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am changing the datatype of a determined columns in pandas and I would like to keep the nan values as np.nan

After executing the following command:

```
df = df.astype({"raw_salary_from": str, "raw_salary_to": str})
```

What I get is that all the nan's transformed into strings 'nan'. How can I avoid that issue while transforming the datatype of the column?

```
['22000.0',
 '0.0',
 '40000.0',
 '9.5',
 '0.0',
 '0.0',
 '28.0',
 'nan',
 'nan',
 'nan',
 'nan',
 'nan']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the index of those nan's first and then convert them to `np.nan` with `mask`. So:

```
idx_nan = df["raw_salary_from"].isna()
df["raw_salary_from"] = df["raw_salary_from"].astype(str).mask(idx_nan, np.nan)
```

Comment: Nice!! Is there a way to apply to multiple columns at a time? like in `df = df.astype({"raw_salary_from": str, "raw_salary_to": str})`

Comment: I wouldn't apply `mask` to different columns as the nans on both columns are likely at different indexes. I would go with a for loop in this case if I'd want to apply this method to many columns.

Comment: Maybe something like this could be a good way
`columns_to_change = ["raw_salary_from", "raw_salary_to"]
    for column in columns_to_change:
        idx_nan = df[column].isna()
        df[column] = df[column].astype(str).mask(idx_nan, np.nan)`

Comment: Yeah, that's simple enough.